# How to define what are the components of a heterogeneous job?

Tags: slurm

I am trying to learn how to use heterogeneous jobs with Slurm. I've been reading [this resource](https://slurm.schedmd.com/heterogeneous_jobs.html) on their official website but I really don't understand how the setup should look like. I understand that heterogeneous jobs are started with this piece of code they've provided:

```
$ sbatch --cpus-per-task=4 --mem-per-cpu=16g --ntasks=1 : \
         --cpus-per-task=2 --mem-per-cpu=1g  --ntasks=8 my.bash
```

However, what I don't understand is how do I define what is the first task and what is the second task. For example, let's say that I have two R scripts in the same folder called `script_1.R` and `script_2.R` I want to submit them to some cluster via Slurm as a heterogeneous job, and I want to request 16 GB for the first one and 1 GB for the second one. Where is the part of the script in `sbatch` where I provide the path to the files for each task? Or is it done somewhere outside of the `sbatch`? How does this work? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand it, the tasks have to be specified in the script (in your example `my.bash`). There, the tasks have to be submitted to the `srun` command.

I think in your example it should look somewhat like the following:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
srun Rscript path/to/script_1.R : Rscript path/to/script_2.R
```

Disclaimer: I have no idea if this works. It's just what I figured after reading the [documentation of srun](https://slurm.schedmd.com/srun.html) and the [heterogenous job documentation](https://slurm.schedmd.com/heterogeneous_jobs.html).